# Switch statement with OR in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to use switch statement with 'ORs'.

I was often using this method in Shell script but it didn't work when trying it in C Programming.

Example in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "aze\n";

    int len = strlen(str);
    char c = str[len - 2];
    
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'a' || 'e' || 'i' | 'y' || 'u' || 'o':
        printf("1");
        break;
    default:
        printf("2");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution

```
2
```

shouldn't this work ?

Comment: @leopardxpreload c is in this case 'e'

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but you may want to check out the standard function `strchr()`. Most of that code can be simplified down to:: `if ( strchr("aeiyuo", str[len-2]) ) puts("1"); else puts("2");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The case you have in your code is not able to perform right calculations, as

```c
case 'a' || 'e' || 'i' | 'y' || 'u' || 'o':
    ...
```

gets evaluated into `case 1` (or we may say `case true`) everytime, as all ASCII values of these characters are values above 1.

You could fix it using multiple `case` one after another:

```c
case 'a':
case 'e':
case 'i': 
case 'y':
case 'u': 
case 'o':
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': case 'y': 
    printf("1");
    break;
```

relying on multiply-case-labeled statements (or on implicit fallthrough, if puts some `;` in between there as well).

`case 'a' || 'e' || 'i' | 'y' || 'u' || 'o':` is syntactically correct but equivalent to `case 1:` (because at least one of of the `||` arguments is nonzero => `('a' || 'e' || 'i' | 'y' || 'u' || 'o') == 1`).

---

Think of C switches as always conceptually equivalent to jump tables rather than as just syntactic sugar for `if-else` ladders.

The case labels are not evaluated at runtime. In fact, they're required to be integer constant expression, exactly so that they can become static indices to a jump table (perhaps after some offsetting if the compiler deems that to be a good idea).

Your corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "aze\n";

    int len = strlen(str);
    char c = str[len - 2];
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': case 'y':
        printf("1");
        break;
    default:
        printf("2");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

could be equivalently expressed with the following jumptable encoded with some GNU C extensions (supported by clang, gcc, tinycc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "aze\n";

    int len = strlen(str);
    char c = str[len - 2];
    static const void *jumptable[256]={
        [0 ... 255]=&&two_lbl, //prefill, using the ranged-designator extension
        //overrides for aeiouy:
        ['a']=&&one_lbl,
        ['e']=&&one_lbl,
        ['i']=&&one_lbl,
        ['o']=&&one_lbl,
        ['u']=&&one_lbl,
        ['y']=&&one_lbl,
    };
    goto *jumptable[c]; //using the labels-as-values extension
    one_lbl:;
        printf("1");
        goto break_switch_lbl;
    two_lbl:;
        printf("2");
        goto break_switch_lbl;
    break_switch_lbl:;

    return 0;
}
```

and that's indeed how a compiler might choose to implement it.

It could do an if-else ladder instead if it considers that faster for your particular case layout, but conceptually, it can always do the jumptable thing, and that's why there is the integer-constant-expression requirement
on the case labels,  that's why `||` doesn't make sense there, and that's why constructs such as the [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) work.